# AS3 gotoAndPlay after video finishes playing

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I have loaded a video wit this code

```
var video:Video = new Video(1440, 900);
addChild(video);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
video.attachNetStream(ns);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(e:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;
ns.play("introAPOK_blanco.f4v");
```

now I need to perform a "gotoAndPlay" to go to another frame or scene after the video finishes playing

Thanks!!

Comment: you need to add an event listener to your net status `ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatusChange);` then check the `event.info.code` for the `NetStream.Play.Stop` code

Answer (score 0):

```
video.addEventListnere("complete", onPlayFinished);

function onPlayFinished(event:Event):void
{
    //Video playback finished
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

1. Check this tutorial http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html
2. instead of "complete" use VideoEvent.COMPLETE

Comment: It doesn't look like "complete" is dispatched by a `Video` instance. See the [event summary here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html#eventSummary).

Comment: Yes, it is not  "complete" it is  video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, onPlayFinished);

Comment: Also you may want to check this link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html

Comment: Yeh, so that's an event dispatched by `FLVPlayback` not `Video`, which is what the OP is using...